# How to use async operation in IO-Bound with TaskCompletionSource?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, taskcompletionsource

I want to implement an asynchronous mechanism in *IO-Bound*, and how can I implement this with *TaskCompletionSource* without consuming a new thread?

This following sample to create new thread in thread pool, but I am looking for a new approach by TaskCompletionSource **without create new thread in thread pool**?!

```
public static Task RunAsync(Action action)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Object>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
    {
        try
        {
            action();
            tcs.SetResult(null);
        }
        catch(Exception exc) { tcs.SetException(exc); }
    });
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: What is action? It heavily depends on the underlying implementation of action, and is not something that you can just transparently transform without consuming a thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Task.Run(() => action())`, but under the hood it will delegate it to the `ThreadPool`. And also the `ThreadPool` will not necessarily create a brand new `Thread`, it usually has some threads that are being reused.

Comment: How this will differ from `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` which should reuse threads from `ThreadPool` also? I highly suspect that OP wants somehow to perform IO-bound operation without consuming thread while waiting for response.

Comment: It will not differ in any way, that's why I said that both things do almost the same thing, the only difference is that he is writing boilerplate code with the TaskCompletionSource.